# I'm trying unsuccessfully to disable the dark theme in @nuxtjs/vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

Logically, I have everywhere exposed that the dark theme is disabled. This can be viewed, for example, in the developer console: [$vm0.$vuetify.theme.isDark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY2YY.png), [$vm0.$vuetify.theme.disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjsNp.png), [$vm0.$vuetify.theme.dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl6Jm.png).

In the *nuxt.config.js* in the connections and settings section of vuetify, the following declarative code:

```
buildModules: [
['@nuxtjs/vuetify', {
  theme: { disable: true },
  treeShake: true,
  defaultAssets: false,
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'md'
  }
}],
// ...
]
```

Despite all this, the Vuetify components add the *theme--dark* class to the list of classes: [html in the developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leSh5.jpg).

As a result, all styles are redefined. White text on a white background, etc. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this :

```
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  ],

  // Vuetify module configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify)
  vuetify: {
      theme: {
        dark: false, <--- here
      },
  },
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help. The result is the same as it was. The theme--dark class is added to the list of classes and overrides the styles.

Comment: This has nothing to do with generated .theme--light or .theme--dark css classes. It will select the light theme as default appearance.